# Weak Slater's condition

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

The famous Slater's condition states that if a convex optimization problem has a feasible point $x_0$ in the relative interior of the problem domain and **every** inequality constraint $f_i(x) \le 0$ is strict at $x_0$, i.e. $f_i(x_0) < 0$, then strong duality holds for the problem. I know how to prove this.

The weak Slater's condition is same as its strong form, but it only requires **every non-affine** inequality constraint $f_i(x) \le 0$ is strict at $x_0$. The weak condition also implies strong duality. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: How did you prove strong duality with the non-weak condition? Why does the weak condition makes your proof non-valid?

Comment: @iarbel84 I learn a proof for non-weak condition from Boyd's <Convex Optimization>, chapter 5.3. The proof assumes the equality constraints Ax=b has a full row rank matrix A without loss of generality. If I want to prove the weak condition theorem in the same way, I need to assume that if we combine the matrix C in the affine inequality constraints Cx<=d with A to form a big matrix, i.e. (C;A), the big matrix (C;A) has full row rank. I don't know why the assumption don't cause loss of generality.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that Slater's condition does not assume that $A$ is full row rank, this is done only in the proof to simplify it (to get a contradiction at the end of the proof). Hence you can convert the affine constraints to the form $Cx\leq 0$, then add a slack variable $s\geq 0$ and get $Cx=-s$. In the same way the proof has a rank assumption on $A$ you can assume the same on the concatenation $(C|A)$. More importantly, notice that all the conditions together eventually imply that the de facto **relative interior** is not empty, this is the real meaning of the differentiation between affine and non-affine constraints. Recall that the constraints eventually define "true" feasible region, and splitting that region between a set $D$ and other constraints is a notation difference only (for convenience purposes).

At the end of the day, Slater's condition means that the "true" feasible set is **convex**. Because if the intersection of the set $D$ with a non-affine constraint is of the form $f_i(x)=0$, we have a **non convex** de facto set. If the same intersection between $D$ and an affine constraint is of the form $f_j(x)=0$, we still have a convex feasible region. And since the proof of strong duality relies on strict separation we must have a feasible convex set with non-empty interior.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, since weaker form of Slater condition requires less, it implies the stronger form, and neither can I find a proof of it in Boyd's textbook.

My solution is that if there are $p_1$ inequalities that are affine and $p_2$ inequalities that are not necessarily affine, we can always divide $D$ into $2^{p_1}$ subregions, $D_0,\cdots,D_{p_1-1}$, in which

$D_i=\{\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x}\in D,\quad f_{i}(\mathbf{x})=0\quad if\quad i\equiv 0({\rm mod}2^{i-1})\quad otherwise \quad f_i(\mathbf{x})<0\quad {\rm for}\quad i=1,\cdots,p_1\}$

And for every non-empty subregion, a subproblem $P_i$ can be defined, by turning all non-strict affine inequalities to equality constraints. Similary, we can define $L_i$, $p^*_i$, $d^*_i$.

I will neglect details here, but it's not hard to prove that in each region $L=L_i$, and it can be further proved that for each non-empty region $D_i$, $p^*\leqslant p^*_i$, $d^*_i \leqslant d^*$.

The feasible point $\mathbf{x_0}$ definitely belongs to one of the subregions $D_i$, meaning that this region is non-empty. More importantly, existence of $\mathbf{x_0}$ makes strong Slater condition hold for problem $P_i$, thus $p^*\leqslant p^*_i = d^*_i \leqslant d^*$. Due to weak duality $p^*\geqslant d^*$, we can only have $p^*=d^*$, which means strong duality holds.